# Combined delayed function calls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom-events, settimeout

I am not quite sure what the technical term for this is. I have a GUI with interactive graphics. After the user has interacted with the GUI, I need to perform some CPU intensive action. However, user input is very frequent, so I only want to call the function after e.g. 1000ms of no userinput. Below the pattern that I use:

```
scheduler = (function(){
    var timer;
    function exec(call, delay){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(call, delay);
    };
    return exec;
})()
```

I.e. if the 3 calls to `scheduler` are done right after each other, only the final one will actually be executed:

```
scheduler(function(){alert('foo')}, 1000);
scheduler(function(){alert('bar')}, 1000);
scheduler(function(){alert('zoo')}, 1000);
```

It seems to work, but it feels a bit hacky I am a little worried about any caveats of Javascript `setTimeout`, especially the scoping problems. Does this seem like a reliable pattern I could use on a larger scale? Will the inline function that I pass to `scheduler` be able to lookup all objects in its lexical scope as usual, when it is called by `settimeout`? What about if I have several of these scheduler instances? Could they interfere with each other? Is there an alternative way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Did you want only the last action to run or did you want all of the actions to run?

Comment: Common situation with common solution. You need `throttle` or `debounce` function (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ or http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/ or something similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `debounce` [function](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) in underscore.js does exactly this:

> **debounce** `_.debounce(function, wait, [immediate])`
>
> *Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function that will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have
>   elapsed since the last time it was invoked. Useful for implementing
>   behavior that should only happen after the input has stopped arriving.
>   For example: rendering a preview of a Markdown comment, recalculating
>   a layout after the window has stopped being resized, and so on.*

Answer (score 1):

You could opt for using web worker threads instead:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: While I tend to agree his target audience might not. :p

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/4XXQ4/1/

```
    var severQueue = [];
    var delay;

    $("#inputSquare").mousemove(onMouseMove);

    function onMouseMove(){
        if (delay){
           clearTimeout(delay);
        }
        serverQueue.push("doSomething")
        delay = setTimeout(sendToServer, 1000);
    }

    function sendToServer(){
        console.log(serverQueue.length);
        delay = null;
        $("#inputSquare").addClass("activated");
        // do some ajax using serverQueue
        // we'll just simulate it with another timeout
        for (var i in serverQueue){
            serverQueue.pop();
        }
        onComplete = setTimeout(onAjaxComplete, 1000);
    }

    function onAjaxComplete(){
        $("#inputSquare").removeClass("activated");
    }

​
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory, your solution looks like it will work. There are no scoping problems related to you passing a callback function to your `scheduler` function; the callback will close over whatever environment it was created in, just like any other function in JavaScript. That being said, [scoping rules can be a bit tricky in JavaScript](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting), so make sure that you read up on it.

In practice, there may be some browser-specific issues related to `setTimeout` that may make this solution unworkable. For example, the frequency at which certain browsers execute `setTimeout` callbacks may vary such that you'll be waiting longer than you expect for a callback to be executed. All `setTimeout` callbacks will be executed sequentially; they'll never be executed in parallel. However, you have guarantees as to what order they will be executed in.

All that being said, any major gotcha in your solution will likely have more to do with the callbacks that your registering rather than the way in which you're registering them.